# Getting all command line args when OpenMPI `prun` calls a C program

Tags: c, command-line, mpi

**Important**: I realized this question seems (at least partially) to pertain to the particular compute cluster that I am using because `prun` appears to be combined with `SLURM` in some way; but it may still have relevance to the use of OpenMPI's `prun` in general.

**Question**:
I want to create an array of strings in a C program whose elements are *all* the command line arguments used to execute a C-program *called* by `prun` (see [OpenMPI: `prun`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v3.1/man1/prun.1.php)). This is what I mean:

```
# prun calls the C-program
prun -v -<some variable number of cores> \
  -np <variable number of compute nodes> \
  <other args to prun> \
  ./name_of_c_program <args to c_program>
```

So in `name_of_c_program.c` I would want to be able to have access to something like

```
// the c-program should have access to *all* command line arguments
// (i.e., including prun's args)
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  all_cmd_line_args = get_all_cmd_line_args();
  // all_cmd_line_args = {"prun", "-v", ...}
}
```

I know already that by default, `argv` will have the name of the program, in this case `name_of_c_program`, as its first element, and then the remaining elements of `argv` will be the arguments denoted by `<args to c_program>` in the first code block of my question.

**Note on `prun`**:

Based on `prun` (see [OpenMPI: `prun`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v3.1/man1/prun.1.php)), it looks like it might do some sort of setting of environment variables. Perhaps I could access the environment variables in the C program in order to get the `options` to `prun` which is used to execute serial and parallel jobs and is called in the following format: `prun [ options ] <program> [ <args> ]`.

**Current (Possibly Environment Specific) Solution**

I assume this is not a general solution, but I did discover that for the particular cluster I am using, the `prun` command sets environment variables for all processes and stores those environment variables in a temporary text file whose name matches the pattern `".PRUN_ENVRIONMENT*"`. To get information like `"PRUN_CPUS=<some number of CPUs>"`, it is simply a matter of reading this temporary file and storing the results in variables in my C program.

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve. `printf("prun -v -1 -np 2 -script <other args> ./name_of_c_program");` Please [edit] your question and add more details.

Comment: Seems like `all_commandline_args` contains exactly what you ask for

Comment: Doesn't `argv` (as in `int main(int argc, char** argv)`) already contain all the command line arguments including the name of the program.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: The command line is only a user interface, when a program gets executed it is passed a set of arguments by the calling process, so if prun doesnt do that then it may not be possible the way you are thinking. But maybe prun exports some environment variables?

Comment: @Bodo I have made edits to clarify what I would like to achieve. Hopefully, this is clearer.

Comment: `prun calls the C-program` how exactly does it "call"? `fork + exec` or just `exec`? What operating system are you using?

Comment: this information is not available in the environment created by `prun`. Maybe this information can be retrieved via `PMIx` api and this is something you can ask at https://github.com/openpmix/prrte

Comment: When you execute `ps aux` when your command is running, do you see the process `prun`?

Comment: To me it is still not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to create a program `name_of_c_program` which will be called from `prun`, and this program is supposed to find out all arguments that were supplied to `prun`? This requires an interface provided by `prun` or its caller or would be possible in non-portable ways under certain preconditions. What program calls `prun` and how exactly does it do this? Maybe you could replace `prun` with a wrapper that saves all command line arguments before calling the real `prun`.